# Does having multiple columns in a view vs lesser columns in Select in a view impacts performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a customer_view where there are 6 fields
`ID , Name , Email , First_Name , Last_Name , Status`.

Whenever I query on view , I always query on Name and ID.

Should I create another customized view Customer_Custom_view with Fields ID and Name only?

Will this impact performance in any manner?

```
Select Id from users
where customer_id = (select id from customer_view where name ='XYZ');

Select Id from users
where customer_id = (select id from customer_custom_view where name = 'XYZ');
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?

Comment: In most cases the performance will be the same. Modern SQL engines handling this situation easily. The main factor there would be the proper indexes.

Comment: Optimizer is smart enough to do a query transform and use an optimal execution plan. Therefore, I don't see any difference in the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the **Oracle optimizer** is smart enough to **transform the query** and use the **optimal execution plan** in both the cases. Therefore, there are high possibility that there won't be any difference at all.

Why not test it and see.

---

### Without Index on base table

**CASE# 1** Existing view

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_view AS SELECT empno, ename, deptno, JOB, sal, mgr FROM emp;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp
  3  where empno = (select empno from emp_view where ename='SCOTT');

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 587534197

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    37 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMP  |     1 |    37 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"= (SELECT "EMPNO" FROM LALIT."EMP" "EMP" WHERE
              "ENAME"='SCOTT'))
   2 - filter("ENAME"='SCOTT')

16 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**CASE# 2** Custom view

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_custom_view AS SELECT empno, ename FROM emp;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp
  3  WHERE empno = (SELECT empno FROM emp_custom_view WHERE ename='SCOTT');

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 587534197

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    37 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL | EMP  |     1 |    37 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("EMPNO"= (SELECT "EMPNO" FROM LALIT."EMP" "EMP" WHERE
              "ENAME"='SCOTT'))
   2 - filter("ENAME"='SCOTT')

16 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

### With Index on base table, and using the indexed column in the filter predicate

**CASE# 1 Existing view**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_view AS SELECT empno, ename, deptno, JOB, sal, mgr FROM emp;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp
  3  where empno = (select empno from emp_view where empno= 7369);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4162864836

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |        |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP    |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_EMP |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN        | PK_EMP |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("EMPNO"= (SELECT "EMPNO" FROM SCOTT."EMP" "EMP" WHERE
              "EMPNO"=7369))
   3 - access("EMPNO"=7369)

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**CASE# 2 Custom view**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emp_custom_view AS SELECT empno, ename FROM emp;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM emp
  3  WHERE empno = (SELECT empno FROM emp_custom_view WHERE empno=7369);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4162864836

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |        |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| EMP    |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_EMP |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN        | PK_EMP |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("EMPNO"= (SELECT "EMPNO" FROM SCOTT."EMP" "EMP" WHERE
              "EMPNO"=7369))
   3 - access("EMPNO"=7369)

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, the explain plan in both cases is exactly same.

Comment: You can also use DBMS_Plan.Display(format => 'PROJECTION') to see which columns are being selected. Also, in later versions of Oracle the optimiser will remove joins from the query if doing so does not affect the output cardinality and the data from the join is not required.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a big difference depending on the indexes that are created on the underlying tables.

For example, if you have a `CLUSTERED` index only on your table and you are `querying` only `name` and `ID` columns, the other columns are `read` as well. Depending on the type of the other columns the performance can be hit dramatically.

Now, if you create a `COVERING` non-clustered index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TEST ON [dbo].[TEST]
(
    [ID] ASC
   ,[Name] ASC
)
```

and you query again only the `ID` and `name` columns, the SQL query engine will use it. This will reduce in any way the IO operations. How much, depends on the size of your table and type of the other columns.

Comment: I don't get how or why the others columns will be read ???
I am fairly new to sql and do not have deep understanding of the matter. Could you please give me some links where I can get better understanding of the matter.

Comment: Check this series about indexes in `SQL Server` - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/ and you will be able to understand it all.